# Overwrite the terminal output of a bash command that has multi-line output?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash command that I want to run once a second and keep the output showing on the screen. I could do something like the following:

```
while "true"; do foo; sleep 1; done
```

but this creates distracting scrolling. Alternatively, I could do the following:

```
while "true"; do clear; foo; sleep 1; done
```

but this causes the output to flash as it is cleared and written. Is there a good way to just have the output of the command overwrite what is on the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the watch command; something like

> watch -n 1 foo

Comment: `-bash: watch: command not found.`; `man watch: No manual entry for watch` .

Comment: This looks like it should be what I want, but the output is screwed up. The first call to the command by watch produces good output, and then with each additional call the output becomes increasingly messed up. The alignment progressively worsens until I can't even read it anymore. *EDIT*: strangely, if I resize the terminal window the output is good again, but still continues to degrade with each passing call.

Comment: It seems that there is some stderror output that may create this problem (I'm running `watch sudo jmap -heap <pid>`, which begins with four lines of stderror output). If I append `2> /dev/null` to the command outside of watch, this strips the output. However, appending `2> /dev/null` causes the output to be messed up and missing lines.

Comment: @jonderry: I can't really help because I've never had the problem, but you could try piping the output of your command to cat then watch would be dealing with "catted" stuff which it may find easier to deal with ie watch foo | cat

Comment: @Daniel: What operating system are you using? I've just tried on the three Linux operating systems (Opensuse, Fedora and SystemRescueCD) here and they all have it installed - and, as far as I remember, I've not installed it.

Comment: @Neal: piping through cat leads to the same problem.

Comment: @jonderry: ...which I'd have thought would be similar to Fedora. Anyway, watch is usually in the procps package along with top and ps and stuff like that.

Comment: @Neal: Per an additional question I just [asked](http://superuser.com/q/276669/38852), the fix for my problem is to add quotes around the jmap command so that its output is redirected rather than watch's: `watch 'sudo jmap -heap 31945 2> /dev/null'`

Comment: @Neal I'm using Mac OS X, which is a Unix, which is how this question is tagged. `watch` is apparently part of [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net) and can be installed on OS X using Homebrew (`brew install watch`) or probably any of the other Unix package managers.