# How can I fix a problem with standard error screwing up the output of watch?

Tags: bash, unix, watch

Specifically, I am trying to run the following command on both CentOS and Fedora14 (same issue with both)

```
watch sudo jmap -heap 31945
```

However, there are a few lines of standard error that screw up the output after jmap is called more than once:

```
Attaching to process ID 31945, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 14.2-b01
```

These lines are stripped if I run:

```
sudo jmap -heap 31945 2> /dev/null
```

However, if I try:

```
watch sudo jmap -heap 31945 2> /dev/null
```

then too many lines are removed (many lines of the actual output are removed).

Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to tell `watch` that the command it's running should have its output redirected; what you did instead is redirect the output from `watch` itself.

Try this: `watch 'sudo jmap -heap 31945 2> /dev/null'`

Note the new quotes -- this is telling `watch` that that entire thing is the command, not merely the `sudo jmap -heap 31945` part, and thus `watch` is still capable of using standard error itself (which I suspect is the cause of your "lost" lines of output).

Comment: Any suggestions for cases in which the command I want to pass to watch has quotes in it?

Comment: @jonderry Two options: Use different quotes (e.g. `watch 'something "do something"'`), or escape the quotes (`watch 'something \'do something\''`).

Comment: Neither of these works for me. For example, if I run `ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`, I get the pids for all processes. However, `watch "ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'"` gives incorrect field extraction, and `watch "ps -ef | awk -F\' \' \'{print $2}\'"` leads to an unterminated command.

Comment: @jonderry Looks as if I may have lead you astray with the escaping of the single quotes. The first form you tried, however, does work -- after you escape the $ in $2, that is: `watch "ps -ef | awk -F' ' '{print \$2}'"`. See also this page on quoting and escaping in Bash: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting